# R: changing plot colors

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I made the following plot in R :

```
library(MASS)

a = rnorm(100, 10, 10)

b = rnorm(100, 10, 5)

c = rnorm(100, 5, 10)

group <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25) )

d = data.frame(a, b, c, group)
d$group = as.factor(d$group)

  parcoord(d[, c(3, 1, 2)], col = 1 + (0:149) %/% 50)
title(main = "Plot", xlab = "Variable", ylab = "Values")
axis(side = 2, at = seq(0, 5, 0.1),
     tick = TRUE, las = 1)
```

Can someone please show me how to color each line in this plot according the value of "d$group" and add a legend in the corner of the screen?

I think the following line of code changes the color of lines per value of "d$group":

```
parcoord(d[, c(3, 1, 2)], col = d$group)
```

And this line of code creates a legend:

```
legend( "topleft", c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
text.col=c("blue", "red", "yellow", "green") )

title("Legend",
      cex.main = 1.1)
```

But I am not sure how to have the colors from the legend match the real colors. I tried:

```
legend( "topleft", c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
text.col= d$group)
```

But this did not work. Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks

EDIT: is there a way to run the code (provided in the answer) if variable "C" is a factor?

e.g.

```
a = rnorm(100, 10, 10)

b = rnorm(100, 10, 5)

c <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5) )

group <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25) )

d = data.frame(a, b, c, group)
d$group = as.factor(d$group)
d$c = as.factor(d$c)


library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(a:c) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, value, group = rn, color = group)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(0, 0)) +
  geom_line()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = rnorm(100, 10, 10)

b = rnorm(100, 10, 5)

c <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5) )

group <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25) )

d = data.frame(a, b, c, group)
d$group = as.factor(d$group)
d$c = as.factor(d$c)


library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id=c("group","c","rn")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, value, group = rn, color = group)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(0, 0)) +
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(c~.,)
```

I have done some modifications in the code, and you can add c as a factor in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Can "expansion" be replaced with "expand.grid", "expand_limits" or "expand_scale"?  I got an error message "could not find function "expansion""

Comment: Suppose there was another variable f = c .... d = data.frame(a, b, c, group, f) ..... how would the code change? reshape2::melt(id=c("group","c","rn", "f"))
?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `ggplot`.  It's a little hacky, but setting the plot to `group` by row number will produce all of the lines from your original plot.  Then set the `color` aesthetic to `group`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(a:c) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, value, group = rn, color = group)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(0, 0)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: i made an edit to the question using your answer, can you please take a look at it?

Comment: thank you for your reply! is it possible to run the code you provided by using the reshape2 library instead of tidyverse (replace "pivot_longer" with "melt")? E.g. library(reshape2)

f = melt(d)

ggplot(f, aes(variable, value, group = group, color = group)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(0, 0)) +
  geom_line()

Comment: it's a little unusual, and arguably confusing to other users, to take code from one answer (mine), add it as an edit to your question, add new constraints to your problem, and then have another answer appear that starts with the exact code from this answer, but solves your new constraints.  now there are two answers in the same post that are extremely similar.

Comment: sorry for the confusion - i cited your answer in the edit. should I have posted a new question instead? again, I apologize for the confusion